# Querying Couchbase Views using Keys() parameter, can we implement the EqualsIgnoreCase in case of String.?

Tags: couchbase, couchbase-view

I have a use case where I want to query couchbaseViews using the Keys() function like this.

```
ViewQuery.from(documentDesignName, viewName).stale(Stale.FALSE).keys(["riya","astha"])
```

So if in the data base "Riya" would be present , its not returning me anything.
Hence I want to ignore the case of the String.
Any help is appreciated.
Thanks in advance.!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your best option is to emit the keys as lowercase in the view itself. Then you can always compare the keys parameters as lowercase as well.